# Local notification at multiple times like alarm in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, alarm

I am creating an alarm app. I want user set time and Local notification come at that time. For this i am using following code:-

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (localNotif == nil)
    return;

localNotif.fireDate = _datePicker.date;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = @"This is the Alert-Body Text";
localNotif.alertAction = @"Button-Text";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

But the problem is notification comes only once and how i set multiple times for local notification so that it comes for every alarm.

Comment: You create a `UILocalNotification` for every alarm. Just beware that you can only have 64 `UILocalNotification` set for you application.

Comment: @rckoenes. Is this 64 limit new? I've previously created applications with hundreds of scheduled notifications (much to my chagrin, but it was a requirement :()

Comment: @rckoenes, I am new in iOS . This is my question how to create multiple UILocalNotification at run time .

Comment: @JamesWebster the 64 has always been there, only the soonest 64 will be keept. You can read it in the official [`UILocalNotification` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/).

Comment: @sign it the same a you create just one, but then you create multiple.

Comment: @rckoenes, I was intrigued by this.. so I tested it. It seems the documentation is inconsistent with practice. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85412/uilocalnotifications

Comment: @rckoenes, Thanks for reply, can you please let me know how i can repeat the notification according to days like I want it fire every Thursday and Saturday at the same time. is it possible?